# Strange behavior with getline C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple program, where all the 'spaces' will be replaced by '%20'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

    string input;
    cout << "please enter the string where spaces will be replaced by '%20'" << endl;
    getline(cin, input);
    //count the number of spaces
    int countSpaces = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++){
        if (input[i] == ' '){
            countSpaces++;

        }

    }

    int size = input.length() + (2 * countSpaces) + 1;
    //char cstr1[size];
    char *cstr1 = new char[size];
    char *cstr = cstr1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++){
        if(input[i] == ' '){ 
            *cstr++ = '%';
            *cstr++ = '2';
            *cstr++ = '0';
        }               
        else{   
            *cstr++ = input[i];

        }

    }
    *cstr == '\0';

    cout << cstr1 << endl;
    delete[] cstr1;

   return 0;

}
```

I get the following strange behavior:

1. With the test input `"this is strange  "` I get `"this%20is%20strange%20%20his is"` , where I just expect `"this%20is%20strange%20%20"`
2. If I hard code the same string, I get the correct results.
3. Replacing `char *cstr1 = new char[size];` with `char cstr1[size];` & removing the `delete[]` while still fetching the input via `getline` also removes the error.

I am using i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1:

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in a debugger to see what is actually going on in the second loop ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last line must be ***cstr = '\0';** not **==**

Comment: Good catch - note also that if the OP had compiled with `g++ -Wall ...` the compiler would have caught the error for him.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. Looks like I am sleep deprived :P

Comment: These are the times I would like to slap my compiler too

Answer (score 2):

Change the `*cstr == '\0';` in the end of your code to `*cstr = '\0';`
Violà!

Answer (score 2):

```
 *cstr == '\0';
```

this line checks if `*cstr` is equal to `'\0'` or not and return `1` or `0` accordingly

that is wrong as you want to insert the `\0` character at the end of the string
so write single `=` instead of double `=`